# jQuery Show items based on form selection

Tags: jquery

Hey there,
I have a simple problem but can't seem to get the solution working. Basically I have a `select`. Depending on the option selection of this `select` it should display a separate corresponding `select`.

I have a js fiddle going here:
http://jsfiddle.net/FcsBu/22/

any help would be appreciated.
thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to mention that your value for "3 Hour Intro" is different than the id of the drop down list.  You should probably change it to "3hr" rather than "hr" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last selector is wrong

it should be either

```
$("#"+ optionValue).show('fast');
```

or

```
$("."+ optionValue).show('fast');
```

depending on whether the optionValue contains the class of the select you want to show or the id of the select you want to show.

Hope this helps! If it answered your question please click the checkbox next to my answer to accept it!

Answer (score 0):

```
var optionValue = $ (this).val();
    $('#'+optionValue).show('fast');
```

Comment: You do not fix everything. Look at the other selectors

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong selectors

A working js fiddle is here

I made two changes first change the `.selector` to `#selector` because you are using id not class.  second you have to use a selector for the show as well so I added the `#` ID selector to that and concatenated with the `+` to your variable which should not be in quotes

http://jsfiddle.net/Psvab/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably would want to hide the other options if you change selection.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.coursedate').hide();
$('.course_type').change(function() {
    var optionValue = $(this).attr('value');
    $('.coursedate').hide(); // Add this to hide other options
    $('#'+optionValue).show('fast');
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

http://jsfiddle.net/FcsBu/30/